# HTML/CSS- how to make 4 colums of text

Tags: html, css, row, multiple-columns

I have been trying to make a 4 column of pictures and text below each picture and all 4 columns in 1 row. This is what I've got so far:

```css
* {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}
body li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-body li {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}
.livingroom-laundy,
.kithen-bathroom {
  width: 46.5%;
}
.kithen-bathroom {
  float: left;
}
.livingroom-laundy {
  float: right;
}
.main-body,
img,
p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cabinets INC.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="apps.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>House.</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="order.html">Order</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-body">
    <ul>
      <div class="kithen-bathroom">
        <li class="kitchen">
          <img src="img/kitchen1.jpg">
          <p>Looking quality American made craftsmanship? We use only the best materials and cabinet components in our RTA cabinets. Purebond plywood cabinet cases (3/4" thick, formaldehyde-free, made in Oregon), Blum Blumotion drawer slides (full extension,
            soft closing, made in USA), Blum Blumotion hinges (soft closing, made in USA), and premium dovetailed drawer boxes come as a standard with every RTA cabinet we sell!
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="bathroom">
          <img src="img/bathroom1.jpg">
          <p>Our cabinets utilize a frameless and full overlay RTA cabinet construction method. This results in a seamless and high end design that is impossible to rival using outdated construction methods. Combine a frameless and full overlay construction
            method with factory direct premium cabinet components and you will see nothing but beauty and longevity from your new RTA cabinet project. Enjoy your new RTA cabinet project from start to finish, order from Barker Cabinets today!
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="livingroom-laundy">
        <li class="livingroom">
          <img src="img/livingroom1.jpg">
          <p>Ordering RTA cabinets is easier than ever. We offer a state of the art website for placing and tracking all orders. Compile your RTA cabinets order at your own speed, check prices and play around with various options before you place your new
            RTA cabinet order. Ordering RTA cabinets on the internet has never been easier than this!
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="laundry">
          <img src="img/laundry1.jpg">
          <p>It's easy to get started designing your project with our RTA cabinet line. Check out our online cabinet layout tutorials to see how easy it is to begin designing you project using our high end RTA cabinets. Layout and assembly is extremely simple
            and can be performed by virtually anyone!
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I want laundry, kitchen, livingroom and bathroom in each in their own column in 1 row.

Comment: your code is a mess ! and its all over the place. try asking a  particular question!

what i can suggest you is to to use bootstrap 


Use bootstrap table or bootstrap grid!! that should help you!

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a really basic question, and your code is a little messy I'm just going to type a response.

Make a container with width of 100%. Within that container have 4 smaller containers with a width of 25%. One content inside of one div. Have them all float left. Apply clearfix to the parent.

This is a helpful article to help you decide how to tackle your problem. If you don't care about learning nice tidy html and want a quick fix, you could figure out bootstrap columns.http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

```
.container{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.box{
 width:25%;
 float:left;
 }
```